# Import graph from networkx

Tags: qgis, networkx

I have prepared an aggregated DiGraph using big data from a Spark Cluster. The resulting graph structure looks like this:
- Nodes are numbers (bus stop numbers) and have a 'pos' attribute with GPS coords.
- Edges are tuples as connections in between the nodes with attribute 'count', which are the number of passengers.

How can I import this networkx Graph G to qQIS for further analysis?

I tried exporting as shape file but get an error:

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-58-6af13780765e> in <module>()
----> 1 nx.write_shp(G, 'output/shp')

~/.conda/envs/graph/lib/python3.6/site-packages/networkx/readwrite/nx_shp.py in write_shp(G, outdir)
    304     for n in G:
    305         data = G.nodes[n]
--> 306         g = netgeometry(n, data)
    307         attributes, nodes = create_attributes(data, node_fields, nodes)
    308         create_feature(g, nodes, attributes)

~/.conda/envs/graph/lib/python3.6/site-packages/networkx/readwrite/nx_shp.py in netgeometry(key, data)
    227         elif 'Wkt' in data:
    228             geom = ogr.CreateGeometryFromWkt(data['Wkt'])
--> 229         elif type(key[0]).__name__ == 'tuple':  # edge keys are packed tuples
    230             geom = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbLineString)
    231             _from, _to = key[0], key[1]

TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: I think it's better to put an issue in the networkx library https://github.com/networkx/networkx

Comment: Ok. Is the shapefile the standard interchange format for this purpose? Or is csv better?

Comment: I don't know @andi-anderle, put an issue with that information